# How to make GETOPTS option-string options case sensitive?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working with a shell script that has, among others, the following two options:

```
OPT1=false
OPT2=false

while getopts "Alfqru:p:x:s:a:b:c:t:z:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    A) OPT1=true
       ;;
    a) OPT2=true
       ;;
    esac
done
```

Now, when I run this script with either -a or -A, OPT1 is set to true and OPT2 is set to false. When I reverse the two cases, the opposite happens. What I want is for -A to make OPT1 true, and -a to make OPT2 true. So how do I make these options case-sensitive?

Comment: Cannot reproduce that.

Comment: Make sure that you have not set `nocasematch`. (`shopt -p nocasematch` should show `shopt -u nocasematch`; if it shows as `-s`, then the option is set.) `nocasematch` doesn't affect getopts, but it does affect the way the case alternatives are matched.

Comment: @hek2mgl : looks like the OP is suppressing the getopts errors by placing a `:` before the `OPTSTRING`. You shoudl be able to reproduce the errors then.

Comment: In the title you have asked about how to make `optarg` case sensitive. You don't have to make it, they are already case sensitive.  In fact you should be asking how to make getopts  option-string option case sensitive?

Comment: @user2824889 : in fact we need to change the title. `optarg` is actually the variable that `getopts` use to store parameter. for example in `./somescript -a somevalue`, `a` is the option string option and `somevalue` is the $OPTARG.. `getopts` is smart enough to read this automatically.

Answer (score 6):

In your `getopts` command you have put a colon after the small `a` which means it expects an argument. I don't know if you have put this accidentally.

In this case getopts will not accept the `a` argument unless you have entered a parameter for that. ie

`./example -a` results in an error `./example: option requires an argument -- a`

&

`./example -a some_value` runs fine

This is what happens by design of your **optstring**.

Paying heed to the above facts in the below script, which I named **example** :

```
#!/bin/bash
OPT1=false
OPT2=false
while getopts :Alfqru:p:x:s:a:b:c:t:z: opt 
do
case $opt in
A) OPT1="true";;
a) OPT2="true";;
esac
done
echo "OPT1 : " $OPT1
echo "OPT2 : " $OPT2
```

(Note that I have put a `:` in front of the getopts `OPTSTRING` to suppress the errors)

gives me :

```
$ ./example -Aa
OPT1 :  true
OPT2 :  false
```

Here the second parameter a should have a parameter but we have not entered it so getopts didn't accept it, so your OPT2 is false.

```
$ ./example -aA
OPT1 :  false
OPT2 :  true
```

Here there is only one parameter afterall because the **A** that follows `a` will be considered an argument to `a`. **A**, the parameter will be stored in the `$OPTARG`

```
$ ./example -a -A
OPT1 :  false
OPT2 :  true
```

Here too, there is only one parameter because the **-A** that follows `a` will be considered an argument to `a`. **-A**, the parameter will be stored in the `$OPTARG`

```
$ ./example -a somevalue -A
OPT1 :  true
OPT2 :  true
```

This is the expected behaviour.

```
$ ./example -Aa somevalue
OPT1 :  true
OPT2 :  true
```

This too is the expected behaviour.

You may consider taking off the `:` after the `a` if you have put it by accident.  Then you will get :

```
$ ./example -Aa
    OPT1 :  true
    OPT2 :  true
```

&

```
$ ./example -aA
    OPT1 :  true
    OPT2 :  true
```

Comment: The : after the a was on purpose; I just simplified the code a bit before I put it here. Anyways, I figured out the error - someone else threw in "shopt -u nocasematch" at the beginning of the script. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: :-) . nocasematch is almost always the villain if we are sure that we are doing it right

Comment: @user2824889 : `shopt -s nocasematch` had no effect in my cygwin though. I guess you need a complete linux environment to check this out.

Comment: @user2824889 - Your comment about `nocasematch` should be posted as an answer.